# Return vfs insted of file

Tags: java, jboss, classpath, vfs

I upgraded my web application from JBOSS 5 to JBOSS 7. In my web application for getting the jars which containing  specific files i am using the following lines of code.

```
static final Pattern _URLJarNamePattern = Pattern.compile(".*[/\\\\](.+)\\.(jar|zip)\\!/.*");;
 try {
                urls = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/config.properties");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new AWGenericException(e);
            }
            while (urls.hasMoreElements()) {
                URL url = urls.nextElement();
                Matcher m = _URLJarNamePattern.matcher(url.toExternalForm());
                if (m.matches()) {
                    String jarName = m.group(1);
                     System.out.println(jarName);
                    _AWJarUrlsByName.put(jarName, url);
                }
            }
```

In my old case (JBOSS 5 server) the `url` string looks like:

```
jar:file:/D:/JBOSS5/3.2.0/server/default/deploy/appl.war/WEB-INF/lib/app.myapp.jar!/META-INF/config.properties
```

Here when i run the above code in JBOSS 5 it works successfully according to the pattern which i enter and it outputs the jar file name (here it is `app.myapp`)

But in the case of JBOSS 7 the `url` string looks like follows which results the wrong output according to above pattern

```
vfs:/E:/Servers/jbossas7/standalone/deployments/appl.war/WEB-INF/lib/app.myapp.jar/META-INF/config.properties,
```

My question is why it gives two output for same code ? Is it possible to fix it without any code change ?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS 7 uses VFS . See https://community.jboss.org/thread/170388#715560 for how to access VFS 'absolute url'

```
while (urls.hasMoreElements()) {
    URL vfsUrl = urls.nextElement();
    URLConnection conn = vfsUrl.openConnection();
    VirtualFile vf = (VirtualFile)conn.getContent();
    //not sure if 'url' points to a vfs 'content' dir 
    //which parent dir has the actual file you are interested
    //yet, it is file:// not vfs:// path in url, now
    URL url = VFSUtils.getPhysicalURL(vf);
    Matcher m = _URLJarNamePattern.matcher(url.toExternalForm());
    if (m.matches()) {
        String jarName = m.group(1);
         System.out.println(jarName);
        _AWJarUrlsByName.put(jarName, url);
    }
}
```

If you try to get classpath jar URLs of appl.war following is not possible in JBoss AS 7 which is however possible at least in Tomcat 7:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URLClassLoader cl = (URLClassLoader) classLoader;//classcast exception in JBoss AS 7
URL[] urls = cl.getURLs();
```

For JBoss AS 7 classpath jars following snippet creates URL array of classpath of your appl.war

http://pastebin.com/YjNwdePr

Comment: checkout this https://github.com/matmsh/tapestry-spring-security-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/nu/localhost/tapestry5/springsecuritytest/services/JBoss7ClasspathURLConverterImpl.java